# Count all distinct values from JSON in javascript for ChartJS

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I got a json dataset that for simplicity sake, looks like the following:

```json
[
  {
    hometown: washington
  },
  {
    hometown: seattle
  },
  {
    hometown: washington
  }
]
```

I am trying to get this data into `ChartJS`, with the labels being `washington` and `seattle`, and the data being the amount of times each hometown gets referenced in the json object.

I tried using the following code, which does output `seattle:1, washington:2` in an object, but even then I'm puzzled how to parse the data into chartJS.

```js
     const hometownCount = apiCallResult.reduce((acc, it) => {
       acc[it.hometown] = acc[it.hometown] +1 || 1;
       return acc;
     }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 const hometownCount = apiCallResult.reduce((acc, it) => {
   acc[it.hometown] = (acc[it.hometown] || 0) + 1;
   return acc;
 }, {});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick search, I found out I was on the right track. I needed `Object.keys(hometown)` and `Object.values(hometown)` to put in Chartjs for things to work.
Cheers